# Django-Markdownx MarkdownxModelAdmin template error

Tags: django

I tried to test Django-Markdownx in my django project, but it keeps makes error. Here is my models.py.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

from markdownx.models import MarkdownxField

# Create your models here.

class Article(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
article = MarkdownxField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

And, here is my admin.py.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from markdownx.admin import MarkdownxModelAdmin

from .models import Article

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Article, MarkdownxModelAdmin)
```

I did as docs example said, but it keeps make an error like below, when I tried to select any Article objects in admin page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoJyl.png)

I confirmed that if I change the Admin.admin to TextField(), it works properly.

Need help..

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot adding `markdownx` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # [...]
    'markdownx',
)
```

[docs](http://neutronx.github.io/django-markdownx/getting_started.html)